# How can I print the current date and time and a string to one line in a file in C?

Tags: c

I have a log file in my C program which I am trying to make entries to every time the user executes a query. It works, apart from it prints the date and time to one line and the activity string to the line below. I need it to print the whole entry to one line. I have tried everything and don't understand why it won't work. I think it is something to do with the time_string. Please can someone help? Code is shown below;

```
/*
 * This function writes a log to the log file.
 */
 void write_log(char *activity) {
     FILE *lf;
     time_t current_time;
     char *time_string;

     current_time = time(NULL);
     time_string = ctime(&current_time);
     strcat(time_string, activity);
     lf = fopen("logs.txt", "a+");
     fprintf(lf, "%s\n", activity);
     fclose(lf);
 }
```

The function is called in the main and is passed a string literal for the activity.

Comment: By "doesn't work", do you mean it crashes? What output are you getting if this is not the case?
**edit:** Nevermind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [man ctime](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime):

> The call `ctime(t)` is equivalent to `asctime(localtime(t))`.
>   It converts the calendar time `t` into a null-terminated string of the form
>       **"Wed Jun 30 21:49:08 1993\n"**

so a `\n` character is included in the resulting string. You must remove the new line character:

```
char* nl = strrchr(time_string, '\n');
if (nl) *nl = '\0';
```

Also worth noting, from the same linked reference page:

> The return value points to a statically allocated string which might be overwritten by subsequent calls to any of the date and time functions.

This is important for the reason stated *and* it is unknown how large that buffer is so using it as the target in a `strcat()` is unsafe due to possible buffer overrun. Instead of performing a `strcat()` remove the new line character and perform two writes to the file; one for the `time_string` and one for the `activity\n`.

Comment: Thank you, how can I remove the new line character?

Comment: You can locate it using `strrchr()` and just set it to `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The string returned by `ctime` ends with a newline. See `ctime(3)`.

Also, you're trying to modify the string returned by `ctime`, which is a static buffer used by the C library. This can lead to a buffer overflow.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
fprintf(lf, "%.*s %s\n", strlen(time_string) - 1, time_string, activity);
```

The `%.*s` will will remove the trailing new-line of time_string since the specified precision is the string length - 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
void write_log(char *activity) 
{

     FILE *lf;
     time_t current_time;
     char *time_string;
     int length = 0;
     char *line = NULL;

     current_time = time(NULL);
     time_string = ctime(&current_time);
     length = strlen(time_string) + strlen(activity) + 1;
     line = (char *)malloc(length);
     if(line){
        memset(line,'\0',length);
        strncpy(line,time_string, strlen(time_string)-1);
        strcat(line," ");
        strcat(line,activity); 
        lf = fopen("logs1.txt", "a+");
        fprintf(lf, "%s\n", line);
        fclose(lf);
        free(line);
     }
 }
```